# How do I communicate about a rejected edit?

Tags: discussion

I have a [proposed edit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/3919) that was misunderstood and rejected. How do I communicate about that?

Comment: Using chat (if they're there or they're regulars) or commenting on one of their posts would be the way. Since I'm here anyway, what did you want to communicate about that?

Comment: Does it makes sense to try a different edit that's a bit more explicit, or is that just irritating?

Comment: In this case, I'd say it was fairly obvious from the existing wording as to what that option did. Moreover, you already commented on it on it once and Vitaliy explained that these are the only 3 available options. So the new comment expressing surprise that the option didn't work as you had expected and the edit seemed like you had just forgotten your previous interaction. In any case, if you want to take another stab at it, by all means, go ahead. There is always room for improvement and if there's a net gain in clarity, I (or anyone else) will approve it.

Comment: Would it make sense in general just link a rejected edit in a comment to the original author to see if he wants work from it, or is that just annoying to the author rather than moderators? (In this particular case, the issue is that his answer only tangentially addresses the actual question, and needs to be reorganized a bit to be relevant.)

Comment: Well, the author _is_ notified of suggested edits to their posts, but the suggestions are also visible (in a queue) to users above 5k rep (35 users as of today), who then vote to approve/reject. If it's rejected before the author sees it, then (if I remember right) the original author does not get a link to the rejected edit. You could put in a suggestion on [metase] (if it's not a dupe) to always include a link to the edit (since a dummy message still remains in the inbox).